# How to extract data from 1st day of the month till today's date -1

Tags: sql, sql-server, sqlcommand

I am trying to extract all the data that has the datetime from 1st day of the month till yesterday, for example:

**01/06/2017 - 22/06/2017**

I have used this code:

```
Select *
from testDb.dbo.Company1
WHERE MONTH(CreatedDate) = MONTH(dateadd(dd, -1, GetDate()))  AND 
      YEAR(CreatedDate) = YEAR(dateadd(dd, -1, GetDate()))
```

*EDIT*

My column for CreatedDate, its data type is DateTime. Not sure if there is any difference tho.

But this prints out all the data from **01/06/2017 - 23/06/2017**. What code should I write such that it will print all data till (today's date-1)? Thanks for the help and have a great day!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this query --

```
SELECT *
FROM testDb.dbo.Company1
WHERE DATEPART(Month, CreatedDate) = Datepart(Month, GETDATE())
    AND DATEPART(Day, CreatedDate) <= DATEPART(Day, Getdate())
```

Edit:

```
SELECT *
    FROM testDb.dbo.Company1
    WHERE DATEPART(Month, CreatedDate) = Datepart(Month, GETDATE())
        AND DATEPART(Day, CreatedDate) < DATEPART(Day, Getdate())
```

Edit 2:

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(30),CreatedDate,120) As [CreatedDate]
    FROM testDb.dbo.Company1
    WHERE DATEPART(Month, CreatedDate) = Datepart(Month, GETDATE())
        AND DATEPART(Day, CreatedDate) < DATEPART(Day, Getdate())
```

Comment: Hi SachinA, thanks for the code! However I am still retrieving data from today! I am only looking at data till yesterday, (today-1). My data type is datetime.

Comment: Yeah right. I missed that out actually. Edited now. Thanks. if it helped you please mark it as an answer.

Comment: do you know to integrate this line of sql statement "SELECT FORMAT(CreatedDate,'yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss') FROM testDb.dbo.Company1;" into the above sql statement u sent me?

Comment: I've edited the query. Is this what you're looking for?

Comment: It sent me 'CreatedAt' is not a recognized built-in function name.

Comment: It was a typo error. Sorry about that. try it out again from above query

Comment: I have created a new post for this problem! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44715341/excel-column-does-not-properly-show-the-date-format

Answer (score 1):

Instead of comparing the month and year components separately, try bounding your result set using a range of two complete data points, one being the start of the month, and the other being yesterday.

```
SELECT *
FROM testDb.dbo.Company1
WHERE
    CreatedDate BETWEEN DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, GETDATE()), 0) AND
                        DATEADD(day, -1, CAST(GETDATE() AS date))
```

## Demo

Comment: Hi Tim, thanks for the help! However I am not retrieving the data that was yesterday. What I am getting is incrementing days, for example, 01/06/2017, 02/06/2017 and not dates like 05/06/2017

Comment: @boobbynick This answers your first sentence `I am trying to extract all the data that has the datetime from 1st day of the month till yesterday` ... if you wanted something else, you should have asked a different question.

Answer (score 0):

I think this `where` clause does what you want:

```
where createdDate >= dateadd(month, 0, datediff(month, 0, getdate())) and
      createdDate < cast(getdate() as date)
```

Comment: Hi gordon! Thanks for the answer but Im getting dates from last month..

Answer (score 0):

This though wont work when today is the first day of the month

```
SELECT *
FROM your_table
WHERE createdDate BETWEEN 
CAST('1 ' + DateName(month, GetDate()) + ' ' +Year(GetDate()) as datetime) 
AND DATEADD(day, -1, GETDATE() )
```